# Should I inherit a subclass if some of the instances don't use an attribute of base class?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, attributes

The question might be a bit unclear, so I'll just provide the code:

```
class HitPoints {
    int m_current;
    int m_maximum;
    int m_regeneration;
};
```

So basically `current` means the hit points you currently have, `maximum` is the maximum hit points you can have, and `regeneration` is how much hp you get every 10 seconds.

Now the thing is; not each creature in my game uses the `regeneration` to regenerate their hp, some just can't regenerate hp over time.

Should I just set `regeneration` to `0` for those creatures, or should I inherit a new class:

```
class HitPoints {
    int m_current;
    int m_maximum;
};

class RegeneratingHitPoints : public HitPoints {
    int m_regeneration;
};
```

I think it doesn't matter that much for this small example, but using the knowledge I've learned, I should inherit a new class.

My question is, does it really matter for one attribute?
And to make it more generic question, how strict is it to create new classes?
Can I sometimes just "bend" a little and use an old class, even if I should inherit a new one?

Comment: Not worth an answer, but I'd just make it zero.

Comment: Agreed - easy to get wrapped around the axle on class design.  Something to be said for simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well obviously I should inherit a new class, since there should be no attributes that aren't used in the base class.

Comment: Just a quick comment. What you said is true for the 99.9% of time. However, in real time or in embedded systems where performance or memory is a concern the first alternative (just one class) is preferred.

Comment: @Pedrom No, the arguments for a hierarchy here are weak at best.

Answer (score 5):

Unless the storage of that extra int would become an issue (if you had a lot of creatures in memory at once), I wouldn't create an entirely new class just to get rid of it.  In my opinion, if you don't regenerate hit points, your hit point regeneration is zero.

Comment: Well I might have up to 500 creatures at once... And your last argument was terrible, with that logic, you could have only one class in your program with all the attributes of each object and set them to zero. If you don't use mana, you got 0 mana. If you can't move, you got 0 movement speed. If you don't use spells, your `vector<Spell*>`-vector is empty.

Comment: When I meant "a lot" I mean ten or twenty million.  And yes, there is a point at which you are being too abstract - but this is not that point.  At least, in my opinion.  If you were to always derive super specifics, you could argue that you'd have RegeneratingHitPoints, SlowlyRegeneratingHitPoints, FastRegenerationHitPoints, etc... but it's your decision where that point of too-much-inheritance is.

Comment: No, you wouldn't have `SlowlyRegeneratingHitPoints` and `FastRegeneratingHitPoits` would have the exact same attributes, only with different values. `RegeneratingHitPoints` vs `HitPoints` is where one of them doesn't need `regeneration` attribute.

Comment: What if they had no maximum hit points?  NoMaxHitPoints?  Eventually you'll work your way down to HitPointCount : public Number and then create a HitPointCountWithRegenerationAndMaximum.  As I said, this is your design decision.  I personally wouldn't make a single object that had zeros for everything not used, but I would consider objects by their logical grouping.  And in this case, it makes sense that HitPoints either regenerate or they don't, but that's determined by the rate of regeneration.

Comment: Also consider that if you want to make generic functions, you'll have to write a specific one for RegeneratingHitPoints and one for NonRegeneratingHitPoints.  You could have an updateHitPoints(HitPoints) function which updates the hitpoints on interval, OR you could do an IF to determine if the object has regenerating hitpoints.

Comment: If I don't want maximum hit points, I'd use `unsigned int health;` instead of creating a new class...? Even if I wanted a class, it'd be like `HitPoints` <- `LimitedHitPoints` <- `RegeneratingLimitedHitPoints`.